# Why Cross Validated instead of Statistics

Tags: discussion, site-name

I am curious why this site is called *Cross Validated*, and not directly called *Statistics*.

Comment: Context: see some early meta posts - for example [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119/the-7-essential-meta-questions) [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-site-be-called-what-should-our-domain-name-be), and [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-to-make-second-round-of-voting-for-the-site-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Early in Stack Exchange history, it was expected that graduated sites would be on their own domain, like http://stackoverflow.com. Since getting a catchy dotcom name at a reasonably cost is tricky, people came out with non obvious names such as http://crossvalidated.com. Then the plan changed, but the name stuck around and the dotcom address now redirects here.

The [blog post by Robert Cartaino](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) explains the reasons for the change of plan. Newer sites are expected to have a name that describes the topic as clearly as possible.